# Reading a file bytes when given as < in terminal using C

Tags: c, unix, terminal

I've looked extensively and can't find this, I'm sure I am searching for the wrong thing.

Anyway, I need to read in a file given in terminal and output the byte code.  I can do this easily enough if I manually enter the file name as a char*, but I have no idea how to even start with this.

A sample would be in the linux terminal:
`$./a.out <test.exe`

And it should print to the terminal the test.exe as byte code.  Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With command line redirections, the program uses `stdin` for reading and `stdout` for writing.

Compile and run this with, for example:
`./a.out < source.c`, or `./a.out < source.c > source.upper`, ...

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    int ch;
    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) {
        putchar((unsigned char)ch);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If, on the other hand, you want to specify the filename as a command line parameter, you can use `argv` to get the filename, as in, for example `./a.out filename.txt`

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc > 1) {
        printf("processing %s\n", argv[1]);
    } else {
        printf("no command line parameter given.\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With the "<" operator in bash what you do is redirect the stdin, that instead of being the terminal is the given file.

So to read a byte you should only do getchar(). And then you can do whatever you want with it. You will receive an EOF when the file is over.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response, it helped so much.

Answer (score 0):

When you use file redirection in a shell, the file is piped into standard input. So you can just read from standard input using `getchar` (or similar) as you normally would.

Your program has no way (in standard C) to know if it's being fed a file or not, or if it's running interactively in a terminal. The best thing to do is just don't think about it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

When you redirect input using `<` you actually gives the content of the file as standard input and you can treat it as such, meaning you don't need to open a file, but to use `getchar()` for example to read the content.